# error Button on keyboard in an app

Tags: java, android

I have a button in the bottom of the activity, when I use the theme
 `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` this when standing on a field looks good, but when I use the theme `@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar` I stop on the field and the button is left on the keyboard, how can I to correct this error?

style file:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Button

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_registrar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        style="@style/boton_verde_next"
        android:text="REGISTRAR"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZV9c.png)

Comment: Any error log ?

Comment: Please, post the XML where you created the button and also some screenshots for OK and NOK cases.

Comment: @W0rmH0le ready